# Editing templates in Adobe Business Catalyst

Tags: business-catalyst

How do I edit the template in business catalyst??  Can I do it from the user interface or do I need Dreamweaver or some other product??
I have googled around, but cannot find an answer....

When I login, I have, on the Website tab, under that there is Site Editor, Web Pages, Blogs & Secure Zones.  Am I missing something or do I not have rights???  I have been told that I am in the Administrator role.

What is a good source for help/how to videos for BC??

AHIA,
LarryR...

Comment: You should also check out http://www.bcgurus.com/tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access templates in Business Catalyst click on Site Manager section on the left and then click on Page Templates (if you do not see this then you don't have permission). Editing a template in BC is really easy, from the most basic sense you just need to know HTML and CSS. Using an FTP manager you can also access to template files by going to the /Template/ folder.

I am not sure if you are an end user or a developer, so the "Develop" (previously File Manager) may not show up if you are not a partner user.

BC Guru's Zero to Hero Program has a bunch of free tutorials: http://bcgurus.com/hero

Or you can get hands on training with the [BC Academe](http://www.bcacademe.com)

Comment: 3 Ways to access Templates:
1) Site Manager > Templates
2) Develop Tab on top of admin area
3) SFTP

For Both #2 and #3 you will navigate to the /Templates/ Folder.

Also, we have made our Developer Level 1 Course available on demand. This covers how to take an HTML page and create a BC Template with the related components such as menus and content holders: http://www.bcacademe.com/tutorials/business-catalyst-developer-level-1-course-video-series

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can edit the template/layout from the user interface. The easiest way to edit CSS and HTML would be by clicking (in the ribbon from the Top) File Manager (alpha). In the left side of the new window you will see a menu which contains all the assets (pages and related CSS).

Hope this helps.