# Styling a form in business catalyst, for data capture

Tags: html, css, forms, business-catalyst, muse

I am very much a novice in the area of **html** and **css**. I have built my whole website in Muse, but my client would like to integrate a database where people can sign up to show interest for the product.

Through research I found out that I had to sign up to the web marketing plan for **business catalyst**, which I have done. I have made a form on business catalyst, to collect the data, but I need to style it so that it fits into with the concept I sent my client (which have now been approved).

How do I style the form? The generic **muse** form is currently on the site, and needs to be replaced with the data collection form, the form in question is on the main screen of http://opzone.businesscatalyst.com.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226991/editing-templates-in-adobe-business-catalyst) answers your question.

This is a tutorial that shows exactly just what (or rather where) to do.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyT-XJHRjtg

In general, you will have to do one of two things:

a) Edit original stylesheets.

b) Add your own stylesheet at the end and override the styling.

Within the video link I put here, notice this part:
[image: Business Catalyst Develop Mode]

The red blocks indicate the files that are being used to style everything within that page. You could simply in the same way add your own custom css file and whatever you write in it, will affect how it looks like.

As I understand you are quite new to all of this and I am not certain that you can get much help when you most likely first need to start with HTML/CSS tutorials, some of the key places that would be a good place to start are:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

http://www.htmldog.com/

http://www.cssbasics.com/